# After Jenkins2.5 update serenity reports are broken

Tags: serenity-bdd

can anyone help me to resolve below issue

I have updated my jenkins version 2.5 ,serenity reports are broken and screenshots are displayed but i can't open them to see those screenshots i have to manually save those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Jenkins bug (or "feature", depending on who you ask). Recent versions of Jenkins by default don't render complex HTML reports correctly. The problem and a solution are discussed here: [Jenkins - HTML Publisher Plugin - No CSS is displayed when report is viewed in Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)