# Jenkins doesn't load CSS at HTML published pages

Tags: jenkins

I have a Java program that uses Selenium to test web sites.
However when I run the program in Jenkins it generates a HTML report. When I open the report I get it with out CSS loaded.

To fix this I usually go to Jenkins->Script console and type in the following command:

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")

(As described here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy)

However after some time this rule is gone, so I need to put it into some config file.

My server is a Ubuntu 18.04 server.
I have installed Jenkins under /var/lib/jenkins
Here I have a file named config.xml, but I cant see any option on this hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins - HTML Publisher Plugin - No CSS is displayed when report is viewed in Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Groovy script file **$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy**, or any **.groovy** file in the directory **$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/** with the following content:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline';")
```

systemctl restart jenkins

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script

Comment: Is there any alternative to this? My company doesn't allow us to change that and we are attaching the page to the build as a separate file but downloading the file for each build is tedious.