# pytest-html report on Jenkins does not have check box for filter and no column sort

Tags: jenkins, pytest-html

--- Problem resolved. see comment ---
pytest-html is great. When viewing the report locally I can click the check box [pass][fail][skip]. I also can click the sort button for each column
[image: pytest html report local]

I use Jenkins "publish html report" to see the report on Jenkins. The column sort button is gone, the check boxes are gone. Thanks in advance.

[image: pytest html report in Jenkins] 

pytest -vs ${test_suite} --url $url --junitxml ${test_suite_xml} --html=${test_suite_html}
pytest-html     1.19.0 
Jenkins 2.121.2
html publisher plugin 1.16

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. Java Script is disabled. 
follow this link to [set Content Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)

`System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")`

What confused me was, nothing seems happen after running that command. Here is why:

```
How to interpret the output:

No output below "Result" header: default protection
Output Result: below "Result" header: protection disabled
Output Result: some text here below "Result" header: custom protection
```