# How to pass --env JAVA_OPTS= to Jenkins inside Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have problem with Jenkins and Css policy (inside docker), i wanted to pass:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS=
"
 -Djava.awt.headless=true
 -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
 'unsafe-eval'; 
  img-src 'self' 
 'unsafe-inline' data:;\"
"
```

Can someone help me? Or is there any permanent solution for this problem?

There is guy commenting IT works for docker without any explanation: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j/46463323#46463323)

Comment: How are you starting your docker container?

Comment: What’s your actual problem?

Comment: With: docker run "container-name"

Comment: David Maze: After running Jenkins Job for Cucumber tests, my reports are not shown properly because Jenkins has strict CSS policy. 

There is solution to set Jenkins script or Jenkins.xml file, but there is no Jenkins.xml inside docker.