# How to view "Protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-report" in Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, protractor, cucumber, report, jenkins-plugins

Am not able to view my Actual **"Protractor report"** in Jenkins.

- I have tried ***"HTML Publisher plugin"*** - Few CSS, Chart/Progress steps and Scenario steps are missing in this report.

[Jenkins - HTML Publisher Plugin - No CSS is displayed when report is viewed in Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)

- I'm using below properties for Jenkins (It's working for Extent report But not for Protractor cucumber report)

i. Goto: "http://localhost:8080/script"

ii. `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *")`

**Note:** I have tried Cucumber Reports Plugin using JSON file.
It looks good. But I want to view Actual Protractor Cucumber report.

**could you please help with the request above? or please suggest me any other Jenkins report generation plugin**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may basically try the similar one on jenkins script page. It worked for me.

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "*");
```