# Report is not fully displaying while using HTML publisher plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, cucumberjs

I am generating reports using protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin in my local system and it is perfectly working.But when i am running this protractor script using Jenkins, I am not able to generate same report there using HTML Publisher plugin.The generated report looks like a broken one.Its not displaying the images and not navigating when clicking on links.I am using Chrome version of 75, Java with jdk1.8.0_201, Jenkins of version 2.263.4 and Html plugin of version 1.25.I have tried below code, but none of them worked for me.

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "*");
```

i am able to disabled the protection.But still report is not fully loading for me.
The actual report is look like [image]

But in Jenkins, after disabling the protection,it look like[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en

Make sure to enable it after you're on the report page, and then reload the page. If this works, I'll explain what happened and what else you can do to permanently fix it

Comment: I have added Disable Content-Security-Policy for Chrome, and enabled it on the report page, but still it is not working for me.

Comment: after you enabled, have you refreshed the page?

Comment: yes, i refreshed the page, but still pie charts are not displaying.

Comment: then I give up :) sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

We need to add all files(css,js etc) while configuring the HTML publisher plugin, as like below[image]

or else we need to keep the 'include files' field as empty. so that it will take all associate files. And then we need to disable the protection by
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)

so that we will get actual report.