# thucydides report from jenkins not opening properly in chrome where it open in iexplorer?

Tags: selenium, automation, thucydides

After a successful run in jenkin a mailer is triggered which contains a thucydide report link.When clicked on the link it open in my default browser i.e. chrome. But it not opening properly the pie chart is not getting displayed and all the test are green. 
Can i change some setting to get it properly?

I want it to open it correctly in chrome n Firefox. As both displays similarly.

Comment: Do you want to open the report in IE or do you want to change the report to display correctly in Chrome? That is not clear from your question.

Comment: Hi I want it to open correctly in chrome.

Comment: Then you would have to include the code of the report here or if it is too much on plnkr or something like that. Otherwise there is no way to help you.

Comment: found a question related to this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740963/missing-pie-chart-and-other-elements-when-display-serenity-report-from-jenkins - will try this